# how to include an image file knowing only name and not extension?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set an image source by a variable name 'fileName'. I only know file name and don't know extensions. extensions may be .jpg, .png, .bmp etc. How i can achieve for different extensions? Here is my code for .jpg extension.

```
 '<img src="../assets/images/logos/' + fileName + '.jpg" width="60" height="40">' +
```

Comment: Why you do not know extensions? Save it to use later. Your best bet would be to list all possible images and match it by name if it's unique

Comment: You'll need help from the server if you don't know the expected URL. E.g. make the URL just `'.../logos/' + filename`, and have the server decide what image format to output.

Comment: I see you're creating HTML in JavaScript. Is there a reason you're not using the DOM's `createElement` instead?

Comment: Why don't you know the extension on what appears to be your own website?

Comment: @Dai my application need to print a web page. css background images are not working for printing a webpage. I tried lot of things like media print.

Comment: @john user upload some images with different extensions such as .jpg, .png etc. we store the image names in database.

Comment: @GaneshDevkate Fix your database to store the file extension then.

Comment: @Dai I am doing a small part of a large application. It will be inconvenient to  change database structure for a small part. There should be an alternative solution.  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the extension you can only do it with multiple requests or with php.

JS:

```
function findExtension(path ,img, name) {
    img.src = path + name ".jpg";
    img.onerror = function() {
        img.src = path + name ".png";
        img.onerror = function() {
            img.src = path + name ".gif";
        };
    };
findExtension("pictures/", document.querySelector("XYZ"), "image1");
```

PHP:
Call a Php file and use glob() to find the file with its extension

```
//Name php file something like: "findExtension.php"
//In Js define the src to the phpfile and add the filename as Get parameter
<img src="findExtension.php?filename=pictureXYZ">

$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$result = glob ("./pictures/" . $filename . ".*");
if (!empty($result)) {
    header("Location: /pictures/" . basename($result[0]));
} else {
    //File does not exists
}
```

I dont think there is any function like glob() in JS. This is based on the nature of js it cant directly work with the filesystem on the server. It would be different if your using node.js as backend. Then this could be easily done.

Answer (score -1):

Use `onerror` to try different possibilities. The example below starts with "filename.jpg" then tries "filename.png".

```
<img
    src="../assets/images/logos/filename.jpg"
    onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../assets/images/logos/filename.png'"

    width="60"
    height="40"
/>
```

Comment: That incurs an additional HTTP request for every image, for every client, for something that *should* be deterministic and not simple trial-and-error. This specific code also makes it hard to test for more than two different extensions… Not a good idea overall.

Comment: @deceze The OP implies his code has no idea what the extension is - so the client code **has** to make different requests (for each possible extension) until it gets a HTTP 200 or runs out of possible extensions.

Comment: Sure, but it must be pointed out that this is really a problem that should be solved on the other end, not on the client side.